# Ruby on Rails: How to start the WEBrick server automatically on Windows in background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-xp, automation, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

In order to run the my Rails application on Windows XP I open a command line, cd to application's directory, and then run `rails server`.

I would like to automate this, such that every time I turn on my computer, all I'll have to do is to type `localhost:3000` in a browser.

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simpler way is to create a batch file with the instruction what you give in the command prompt like

> d:
>
> cd projects\myapp
>
> ruby script\server

and then drop a copy of the file to Windows Start -> All Programs -> start up folder.

Comment: How could I do this such that the command window will not appear ?

Answer (score 1):

You have few possibilities to do that.

using the registry you can use [`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/Startup.htm) or the better approach would be to create a service, you can see this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) with some instruction how to make a service of whatever executable you want.

Comment: Could you suggest how to run it in background, without seeing the Windows command window ?

Answer (score 1):

have you thought about , AUTOEXEC.BAT or creating some batch files. you create right cmd commands that are run at start up. http://www.aumha.org/a/batches.php

Comment: I would like to run it in the background, without seeing the command window. How should I do this ?

Comment: its just like ssri said(very easy, i actually just followed the tutorial to make sure it works), here is a tutorial to not have cmd show up, it stills pops up for a second or can stay untill you press a button either way: http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm#windows

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is turn your application into a service. There is a solution for Mongrel (a web server similar to webrick) called [mongrel_service](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongrel_service), but is not compatible with Rails 3 (due several changes of Rails internals)

However, you can repurpose mongrel_service codebase to work with thin, another webserver that works with Rails 3.

Please look [here](https://github.com/luislavena/mongrel_service/blob/master/src/mongrel_service/mongrel_service.bas#L86) where is the only reference to mongrel_service script. changing it to `thin start` could work.

Perhaps is not the answer you're looking for (as there is some work to be done) but is something :)

Answer (score 1):

start rubyw script/rails server webrick

start -> start in another console
rubyw -> run ruby detached from console