# Rails. How to deploy on a Windows machine without command prompt/command window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, thin, mongrel

I'm studying Rails, i'm a student and I want to deploy some experiment on Windows as a service.

For example:

I need to start my PC with Windows 8.1 and i want to be able to open browser, write `localhost:3000/something` and start my Rails's app.

Is it possible?

I searched a lot on the web but I found only small tutorial with solutions that I think are not too much strong.

you can tell me a serious approach to the problem and a serious solution?

Comment: Do you have administrative access on the machine you are using? It's very much possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: How to start the WEBrick server automatically on Windows in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446154/ruby-on-rails-how-to-start-the-webrick-server-automatically-on-windows-in-backg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an answer in another SO thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4458804/472768

You want to create a batch file with the commands

```
cd path\to\your\app
rails s
```

And add it to your Startup Items folder in the Start Menu

Comment: but with this system I will always command window of the active Windows. Right? I do not want to open a command window.

Comment: Call with `-d`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446154/ruby-on-rails-how-to-start-the-webrick-server-automatically-on-windows-in-backg/4458804#comment5589100_4458804

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the easy install options for ruby and rails, all of which come with a web server.

http://railsinstaller.org/en is one good example.

Comment: It would be a solution only if you're already installing RoR by Rails Installer, otherwise it not makes sense have to install this only to make server autostart w/ windows.